# Cannot access remote files with puppet

Tags: windows, puppet

I can not seem to get puppet to happily grab a file from a network share

```
    file { "installerfile":
        ensure => file,
        source => '\\drivename\installer.msi',
        path   => 'C:/puppetstuff/installer.msi',
    }
```

Fails with a bad URI error. It says that the drive name is a bad hostname:

```
Debug: Reraising Failed to convert '/installer.msi' to URI: bad component(expected host component): drivename
```

How can I properly access the network share?

Comment: Does \\potatodrive open the share in Windows Explorer? Is that the server name? If not, what is the server's name?

Comment: Potato drive is of course not actually the name of the drive, but the drive does open in the explorer happily. The account puppet is running as should have full access to it. In fact if I simply change the resource type to a package with the same source it works fine.

Comment: Your post is anonymised beyond recognition. Consider publishing some information that is not vital, or substituting names coherently rather than at random. - For what it's worth, this is likely a problem from [URI.parse](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file/source.rb#L59). I don't see a clear solution yet.

Comment: Updated with better naming

Comment: Either I'm completely off track or this is a case of Works On Unix. Trying `irb(main):006:0> require 'uri'; URI.parse(URI.escape('\\drivename\installer.msi'))` yields
`#<URI::Generic:0x000000026088b0 URL:%5Cdrivename%5Cinstaller.msi>` without exception. Can you try this on Windows?

Comment: How do I try this on windows? This looks like ruby and I havn't gone that deep into puppet yet. Is there a way to have puppet parse this on the command line like there is with normal puppet DSL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59598/discussion-between-felix-frank-and-derongan).

Comment: the `source` parameter is going to be evaluated on the master. why not give `//drivename/installer.msi` a shot? Just out of curiosity. Are you planning to have puppet install this after the file resource puts it in `c:/puppetstuff/installer.msi`?

Comment: actually. i'm not sure if it is evaluated on the master. but either way `puppet/util` calls `gsub(/\\/,('/')` on the path anyhow, if it is detected as a `unc` path it prepends an additional `/`. So essentially what you have should work and actually translate to `//drivename/installer.msi` so not sure why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in `puppet/util` I have found that you need to escape each slash even when using single quotes:

```
source => '\\drivename\installer.msi'
```

should be

```
source => '\\\\drivename\\installer.msi'
```

Messy irb output below:

```
1.9.3-p547 :036 > path = '\\\\drivename\test'
 => "\\\\drivename\\test"
1.9.3-p547 :037 > puts path
\\drivename\test
 => nil
1.9.3-p547 :038 >     params = { :scheme => 'file' }
 => {:scheme=>"file"}
1.9.3-p547 :039 >  path = path.gsub(/\\/, '/')
 => "//drivename/test"
1.9.3-p547 :040 >
1.9.3-p547 :041 >         if unc = /^\/\/([^\/]+)(\/.+)/.match(path)
1.9.3-p547 :042?>           params[:host] = unc[1]
1.9.3-p547 :043?>           path = unc[2]
1.9.3-p547 :044?>         elsif path =~ /^[a-z]:\//i
1.9.3-p547 :045?>           path = '/' + path
1.9.3-p547 :046?>         end
 => "/test"
1.9.3-p547 :047 > params[:path] = URI.escape(path)
 => "/test"
1.9.3-p547 :048 > params
 => {:scheme=>"file", :host=>"drivename", :path=>"/test"}
1.9.3-p547 :049 > URI::Generic.build(params)
 => #<URI::Generic:0x007f8da327e808 URL:file://drivename/test>
1.9.3-p547 :050 > URI::Generic.build(params).host
 => "drivename"
1.9.3-p547 :051 > URI::Generic.build(params).path
 => "/test"
```

You are safer using unix style paths in this case. `puppet/util` just converts your UNC path to a unix style path anyway.

```
# Convert a path to a file URI
def path_to_uri(path)
  return unless path
  params = { :scheme => 'file' }
  if Puppet.features.microsoft_windows?
    path = path.gsub(/\\/, '/')
    if unc = /^\/\/([^\/]+)(\/.+)/.match(path)
      params[:host] = unc[1]
      path = unc[2]
    elsif path =~ /^[a-z]:\//i
      path = '/' + path
    end
  end
  params[:path] = URI.escape(path)
  begin
    URI::Generic.build(params)
  rescue => detail
    raise Puppet::Error, "Failed to convert '#{path}' to URI: #{detail}"
  end
end
```

So `source => '//drivename/installer.msi` is the safer method to avoid escaping issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly I have tried all possibilities on this front, with no positive results> Also If I remember correctly the puppet docs state that you only need to escape \s if you use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: The docs appear to be wrong in this case. As you can see in the irb output above.

Comment: Ill double check this when I get to a computer running puppet. If it works I will be pleasantly surprised, but I am fairly sure I tried it.

Comment: Sadly the same error pops up no matter how I do the quotes or the slashes

Comment: That is strange. Sounds like a bug to me.